# Issue with ListView Command set custom action | spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, modern

I have implemented a simple listview command set and added one button which is enabled when one item  in a list is selected ( Similar to Command_1 example [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api))

While its working as expected on my List .

However when i add a list(preview) web part on Home page, the custom button added is visible all the time .
-- I have debugged and observed that the extension is not loaded on home page.
Any one encountered similar issues ?

How can i hide the button added by custom action or if i can make it work on the home page also like it works on List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering if anyone else faces similar issue , the response on sp git hub for the same :(https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2641)

- No official docs state List webpart support the SPFx ListView
  Extension. The List webpart is preview, still in developing, so
- no-support to ListView extension is normal now. You can submit
  feature request in the UserVoice.

  As a workaround what i did was to make default text of the custom action button empty and then setting the text when the extension is executing, thats how the button got removed from Home page list view(preview) web part and users are not confused any more to why the button is not working.